# stop win32 window to be minimized programatically

Tags: winapi

i want to stop my win32 window to be minimized programatically , so I did below but its not working. please let me know any other solution or if i am doing something wrong here.

for testing I am minimizing my window after 2 sec& trying to catch that that and maximize my window again. but its not working as expected.

below is the code.

```
case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
            if ((wParam & 0xFFF0) == SC_MINIMIZE)
            {
                ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
                UpdateWindow(hWnd);
            }
            else
                DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

//show & hide for every 2sec
VOID CALLBACK timerelapsed(HWND hWnd, UINT, UINT_PTR, DWORD)
{
    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);
}
```

Comment: Why not simply disable the minimize button?

Comment: i am minimizing my window grammatically with  ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWMINIMIZED);  thnx I edited my question

Comment: exclude `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` from the window style

Comment: "i want to stop my win32 window to be minimized programatically" -- why?

Comment: @MichaelWalz  if ((wParam & 0xFFF0) == SC_MINIMIZE) is from stack over flow again,   is it wrong ??

Comment: @RogerLipscombe client requirement

Comment: "client requirement" -- ask the client why. The "why" is important, because it lets you choose between different solutions, up to and including pointing out that their requirement is stupid.

Comment: If you have a minimize button on your window, the user is going to be surprised that it doesn't work, or does something weird. Surprise is not good.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe when we are switching between desktops, the full screen maximized window is minimizing automatically.

Comment: @Durga not really wrong, but just not necessary.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe its actually a full screen no frame window. user can see anything

Comment: Your timerelapsed() function is simply not performing a realistic test.  You cannot stop a ShowWindow() call.  But you don't have to, just don't program one.

Comment: "when we are switching between desktops". Ah, so maybe you want to look at _why_ that happens, and maybe have something to put the window back when you switch back to the original desktop...? That's _different_ from attempting to subvert the default minimize behaviour.

Comment: @HansPassant is there a alternate, actually we have full screen frame less window which should be maximized for a while but in between if we try to switch desktops it is getting minimized automatically

Comment: @MichaelWalz, from the documentation: "In WM_SYSCOMMAND messages, the four low-order bits of the wParam parameter are used internally by the system. To obtain the correct result when testing the value of wParam, an application must combine the value 0xFFF0 with the wParam value by using the bitwise AND operator." Absolutely necessary.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe yes there is an other window below this, is this causing for this behavior

Comment: @RogerLipscombe OK, thanks for the information, i didn't know that.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe thnx, it's not actually, I tried by removing that window, still the same  issue.

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653(v=vs.85).aspx) for `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`. In particular:

> An application can prevent changes to the window by setting or clearing the appropriate bits in the flags member of WINDOWPOS.